# How to restructure data frame for a certain kind of boxplot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, transpose

I work with R and Rstudio. I got my hands on a longitudinal data frame, it looks basically like this:

```
trait_A_time_1 <- c("2.2","2.9","1.4","3.6")
trait_A_time_2 <- c("4.2","3.2","2.1","4.0")
trait_A_time_3 <- c("2.2","2.5","3.4","1.9")
trait_A_time_4 <- c("3.2","3.9","4.5","4.7")
trait_A_time_5 <- c("2.8","3.3","4.0","1.1")

df <- data.frame(trait_A_time_1, trait_A_time_2, trait_A_time_3, trait_A_time_4, trait_A_time_5)

print (df)

  trait_A_time_1 trait_A_time_2 trait_A_time_3 trait_A_time_4 trait_A_time_5
1            2.2            4.2            2.2            3.2            2.8
2            2.9            3.2            2.5            3.9            3.3
3            1.4            2.1            3.4            4.5            4.0
4            3.6            4.0            1.9            4.7            1.1
```

It measured a certain psychological trait in persons over a few weeks and measurement occasions. And now I want to make a boxplot that looks like this:

[image: desired boxplot]

```
x axis (groups): the four occasions of measurment
y axis: levels of trait A in the sample
```

I tried this code:

```
p <- ggplot(data2, aes(x=, y=)) + 
  geom_violin()
p
```

But it does not work since I have no dedicated variables for the occasions or the level of A. How exactly can I get those? How do I have to transpose/restructure this dataset, to get my desired boxplots?

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible example? A simplified or mock version of your dataframe should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added some sample data. This should do it

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(`trait A time 1` = c(3.3, 2.1, rnorm(10)),
             `trait A time 2` = c(4.1, 2.2, rnorm(10)),
             `trait A time 5` = c(3.9, 1.9, rnorm(10)))

df %>% 
  rename_with(.fn = function(x) gsub('trait A time', "", x)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  ggplot(data = .,
         aes(x = name, y = value)) +
  geom_violin() +
  labs(x = "time", y = "trait A")
```

which results into
[image]

You don't necessarily have to rename like I did here, the gist of the code is in the pivoting with `pivot_longer`.

**EDIT**:

As per request, I will try and shortly explain what the first two lines do. `rename_with()` is a functon from the `dplyr` package that is able to rename column names. It allows several options to rename columns, but in this case I provided a function to rename all columns names. The function simply replaces 'trait A time' in any column name for an empty character ''. It is not the cleanest thing to do, but it serves its purpose.

`pivot_longer()` is a very niche function (also from `dplyr`) which you will likely use more often from now if you are going to continue to work with `R`. Essentially, it is able to transform the dataframe you have into a dataframe with more rows --- making it a *longer* dataframe. Long dataframes are usually the way to go for plotting with `ggplot`. It creates a *name* column and a *value* column, but the names of these columns can also be changed. Notice that every row of this long dataframe provides info for only 1 observation, namely an observation with corresponding name (measurement time in your case) and its corresponding value. Before, you had a *wider* dataframe that contains information of more than 1 observation, which you should maybe imagine it being harder to plot if there is too much info per row to plot.

```
df %>% 
  rename_with(.fn = function(x) gsub('trait A time', "", x)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>% 
  print()
#> # A tibble: 36 x 2
#>    name   value
#>    <chr>  <dbl>
#>  1 " 1"   3.3  
#>  2 " 2"   4.1  
#>  3 " 5"   3.9  
#>  4 " 1"   2.1  
#>  5 " 2"   2.2  
#>  6 " 5"   1.9  
#>  7 " 1"   0.293
#>  8 " 2"   0.274
#>  9 " 5"  -0.869
#> 10 " 1"   2.30 
#> # ... with 26 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you, you solved my problem. I looked up what pivot_longer() does but still don't understand 100%. Can you paraphrase what that line and the one before do in simple terms?

Comment: @E_H I edited my answer and tried to explain a bit more of what the lines do.